# Positive Change, Negative Change, and Total Change with Values on Graph

Tags: visualization, difference-equations, splines

I am trying to show a change in cross-section geometry between years, and have good visual plots but would like actual values to use also. I am using spline curves to visualize the cross sections, dividing the second year with the initial, and am plotting the space between the curves using the following code

```
Difference=Spline1[x]-Spline2[x];
DifferencePlot = 
 Plot[Difference, {x, 4, 23}, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {-2, 2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.003]}, Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> {Red, Green}, ImageSize -> 300, 
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm["(m)"], 
    HoldForm["Area\nchange(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\))"]}, 
  LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}, Background -> LightGray]
```

[image]

I would like to find the total area of green (positive change) and red (negative change, as a negative value) and total (positive change plus negative change) and show them as values on the plot themselves (positive change in green, negative in red and total in black).

I haven't been able to figure this out but any help would be great. I can upload the data used also but an example that will work for any similar spline is good and I can adjust the code accordingly for my needs.

Data used to create the spline

```
Data1={{-3.,52.584},{-2.,52.584},{-1.,52.584},{0.,52.584},{0.690359,52.129},{1.35808,51.935},{2.15814,51.785},{2.83443,51.765},{3.39709,51.703},{3.81911,51.45},{4.31593,51.458},{4.91879,50.931},{5.48303,50.638},{6.05773,50.506},{7.40077,49.892},{7.66482,49.873},{8.36334,49.792},{8.78798,49.792},{9.38703,49.887},{9.79445,49.912},{10.3076,49.967},{10.8794,49.971},{11.2876,50.086},{11.801,50.108},{12.5217,50.166},{13.0028,50.204},{13.4898,50.211},{14.0177,50.281},{14.6184,50.303},{15.0467,50.306},{15.7232,50.349},{16.0804,50.389},{16.7198,50.437},{17.3869,50.424},{17.7724,50.377},{18.1859,50.381},{18.8983,50.345},{19.193,50.289},{21.36,50.87},{21.7722,51.061},{21.8349,51.078},{22.384,51.351},{22.8442,51.574},{23.3637,51.866},{24.,51.866},{25.,51.866},{26.,51.866}};
Data2={{26.,52.143},{25.,52.143},{24.,52.143},{23.3859,52.143},{23.1698,51.942},{21.4912,51.068},{21.0132,50.936},{20.4527,50.861},{19.0339,50.846},{18.3098,50.8},{17.8306,50.793},{17.4658,50.762},{17.0203,50.722},{16.4767,50.717},{15.98,50.732},{15.4513,50.756},{14.9287,50.731},{14.5165,50.699},{13.9742,50.742},{13.4617,50.732},{12.9475,50.715},{12.4889,50.709},{12.0645,50.681},{11.5034,50.651},{11.0292,50.631},{10.4117,50.637},{9.95895,50.625},{9.49877,50.552},{8.9786,50.536},{8.50658,50.518},{8.05728,50.454},{7.51495,50.422},{7.05679,50.455},{6.55668,50.519},{6.01821,50.547},{5.60583,50.617},{5.44458,50.632},{5.12869,51.166},{4.74713,50.97},{3.94958,51.495},{2.66635,51.909},{2.20125,51.93},{1.75397,51.898},{1.24684,52.044},{0.932995,52.128},{0.372399,52.39},{-0.109343,52.729},{-0.565013,52.883},{-1.04139,53.041},{-2.,53.041},{-3.,53.041},{-4.,53.041}}
```

The splines I created

```
Spline1 = 
 Interpolation[Data1, Method -> "Spline", 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3];
Spline2 = 
 Interpolation[Data2, Method -> "Spline", 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3]
```

Comment: Please post a simple example of your `Spline1` and `Spline2`.

Comment: @Domen I added the data for the splines above

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) together with [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html).

```
posArea = NIntegrate[Clip[Difference, {0, ∞}], {x, 4, 23}]
(* 0.346685 *)

negArea = NIntegrate[-Clip[Difference, {-∞, 0}], {x, 4, 23}]
(* 7.80386 *)

totArea = posArea + negArea
(* 8.15055 *)

Show[DifferencePlot, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Column[
    MapThread[
     Style[Text[NumberForm[#1, {4, 3}]], 12, #2] &, {{posArea, 
       negArea, totArea}, {Green, Red, Black}}]], Scaled[{.8, .8}]], 
 Background -> White]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this method but for some reason I am getting errors back with it, I added the data I am using above if that helps solve the issue

Comment: @AndrewBowsher, I fixed the code according to your splines.

Comment: I have tried adding some text above the values to show that it is area change being shown, but I haven't managed to do it successfully. I also cannot figure out how to add another column of data next to this data (laid out the same but with different values I have calculated. It keeps giving back errors when I try to do that

Comment: @AndrewBowsher, Sorry, the syntax with `MapThread` I've used might be a bit advanced, I agree. If you want a simpler version: `Show[DifferencePlot, Epilog -> Inset[Column[{Style[posArea, Green], Style[negArea, Red], Style[totArea, Black]}], Scaled[{.8, .8}]]]`

Comment: That's great, it makes it a lot simpler with my limited coding knowledge! Thanks! I can't figure out how to change the font size to 8 for both of the insets I made, it will only seem to change the font size for one of them when I try. I have added the code I made above if you might be able to give it a quick glance. It has my more complicated names for the data but you should be able to ignore the names for this purpose

Comment: @AndrewBowsher, font size can be set directly inside `Style`, for example: `Style[posArea1u2119, 8, Blend[{Green, Black}, 1/3]]`. Also, I removed your code from the question because it is a completely separate question and will make the whole initial question confusing.

Comment: Oh perfect, it's the first time I have used this so was a bit confused with the exact formatting I should do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or extract the `Polygon` from the `DifferencePlot` and calculate their areas.

```
redParts = 
 Cases[Normal[DifferencePlot], {__, Red, GraphicsGroup[p__]} :> 
      p, ∞] /. Polygon -> Area@*Polygon // Flatten // Total

greenParts = 
 Cases[Normal[DifferencePlot], {__, Green, GraphicsGroup[p__]} :> 
      p, ∞] /. Polygon -> Area@*Polygon // Flatten // Total

total = Cases[Normal[DifferencePlot], _Polygon, ∞] /. 
   Polygon -> Area@*Polygon // Total

total == redParts + greenParts
```

[image]